# C++ и циклические зависимости

Tags: c++, циклические-зависимости

Я хочу понять, существует ли какой-то единый способ лечения циклических зависимостей?

Проблема: по той или иной причине в проекте возникают перекрестные ссылки между типами. Такие ситуации иногда случаются, несмотря на предварительное планирование архитектуры. Такие ссылки не всегда являются ошибками.

Самым неприятным в этой ситуации является то, что в большинстве случаев компилятор выдает тонну уведомлений. При этом, уведомления указывают в неверные места, и только опыт помогает более или менее быстро понять, что причиной является циклическая зависимость.

К тому же, многие постоянно забывают, что `#pragma once` защищает от множественного включения, а не от циклических зависимостей.

К примеру, есть сцена с боем, есть бой, бой содержит ссылку на родительскую сцену:

```
// BattleScene.hpp
class BattleScene
{
    private:
    Battle battle;
};

// Battle.hpp
class Battle
{
    private:
    BattleScene &parent;
};
```

Каков общий способ решения такого вопроса?

Comment: Предварительное объявление...

Comment: Вы уверены, что две отдельные метки "зависимости" и "циклические" - это удачная пара меток для вашего вопроса? В таких случаях следует писать через дефис: "циклические-зависимости". Правда, конкретно эту метку всё равно добавлять не следует, ведь других вопросов по ней нет и она бесполезна.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо за справедливое замечание.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для того, чтобы компилятор не ругался - достаточно использовать предварительное объявление:

```cpp
class BattleScene;
class Battle
{
private:
    BattleScene &parent;
};
```

Замечу, что объявленный, но ещё не определенный класс нельзя использовать по значению, только по ссылке или по указателю.

Однако, с циклическими ссылками есть и вторая проблема: циклические структуры данных невозможно тривиально скопировать или перенести.

Так, если вы попытаетесь сделать вот так:

```cpp
BattleScene copy = someOtherScene;
```

то окажется, что `copy.battle.parent` указывает не на `copy`, а на `someOtherScene`! Поэтому не забывайте запрещать копирование и перемещение!

```cpp
class BattleScene;
class Battle
{
private:
    BattleScene &parent;

    Battle(const Battle&) = delete;
    Battle(Battle&&) = delete;
    Battle& operator=(const Battle&) = delete;
    Battle& operator=(Battle&&) = delete;
};
```

Ещё одна проблема с циклическими структурами - возможная потеря константности. Так, если у вас есть переменная `const BattleScene scene`, то вы можете взять `scene.battle.parent` - и получить неконстантную ссылку на `scene`!

Кроме всего этого, лишние ссылки банально неэффективны по памяти.

Поэтому предлагаю вам рассмотреть альтернативу - передачу родительского объекта параметром в методы дочернего:

```cpp
class BattleScene;
class Battle
{
public:
    void Foo(BattleScene& parent);
};

class BattleScene
{
private:
    Battle battle;

public:
    void Bar()
    {
        battle.Foo(*this);
    }
};
```

Если вам требуется куда-то передавать ссылку на Battle отдельно - можно сделать обёртку:

```cpp
class BattleScene;
class Battle
{
public:
    void Foo(BattleScene& parent);
};

class BattleRef
{
    BattleScene& scene;
    Battle& battle;
public:
    BattleRef(BattleScene& scene, Battle& battle) : scene(scene), battle(battle) { }

    void Foo()
    {
        battle.Foo(scene);
    }
};
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за столь развернутый ответ. Конечно, я понимаю, что ссылку на предка (скорее, владельца) можно передавать в метод в виде параметра, но я не хотел передавать одну и ту же ссылку тысячи раз в секунду при обработке, хотел снять нагрузку с регистров/стека.

Comment: @MGNeo так ведь передача ссылки через регистры или стек работает куда быстрее, нежели обращение по ссылке из поля структуры. А еще существует такая штука, как инлайнинг...

Comment: пожалуй, вы абсолютно правы. Вообще я понял, что код с циклическими зависимостями, - это очень плохо. Простой случай можно исправить предварительным объявлением. Но чуть более сложный - уже нельзя. Я два дня расшифровывал сотни очень мутных ошибок, которые указывали в неясное место. И только по счастливой случайности сообразил, что проблема может быть вызвана циклическими зависимостями. Буду избавляться.

Comment: суть вот в чем. Я хотел дать всем объектам боя ссылку на бой, чтобы объекты могли добавлять в бой другие объекты, например, взрывы и осколки. Для этого я сделал базовый класс, который в конструкторе принимает бой и запоминаем на него ссылку. Затем я отнаследовался различными объектами боя от этого класса. И вся красивая картина модульности рухнула, наполнив консоль сотнями ошибок. Чтобы это собрать, придется написать сотни предварительных объявлений в десятках файлов, а это неприемлемо.

Answer (score 2):

```
// BattleScene.hpp
#include "Battle.hpp"

// Battle.hpp
class BattleScene;

class Battle
{
 private:
  BattleScene &parrent;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Универсальный способ лечения циклических зависимостей можно создать, но только сначала нужно понять порядок объявлений и зависимостей между ними.

Самый первый простой элемент это предварительное объявление типа. Потом объявление класса с их элементами и предварительно объявленными методами. *Только без объявления методов класса внутри него!* Это может привести к невозможности компиляции. Дальше эти самые инлайн функции в хедер файлах и определения простых методов в cpp.

Допустим есть два класса, которые содержат указатель друг на друга и методы с аргументом типа другого класса. Вот пример как всё нужно правильно объявлять :

At.hpp

```cpp
class A ;
```

Bt.hpp

```cpp
class B ;
```

A.hpp

```cpp
# ifndef  CLASS_A_HPP
# define  CLASS_A_HPP
# include "At.hpp"
# include "Bt.hpp"
# include "B.hpp"
class A {
public :
  A ( int ) ;
  void  setB  ( B & ) ;
  B & theB  ( ) ;
  int Pi  ( ) ;
private :
  B * b ;
  int pi  ;
} ;
# endif // CLASS_A_HPP
```

B.hpp

```cpp
# ifndef  CLASS_B_HPP
# define  CLASS_B_HPP
# include "Bt.hpp"
# include "At.hpp"
# include "A.hpp"
class B {
public :
  B ( int ) ;
  void  setA  ( A & ) ;
  A & theA  ( ) ;
  int Pi  ( ) ;
private :
  A * a ;
  int pi  ;
} ;
# endif // CLASS_B_HPP
```

Ai.hpp

```cpp
# ifndef  CLASS_AI_HPP
# define  CLASS_AI_HPP
# include "A.hpp"
# include "Bi.hpp"

inline  B & A :: theB ( ) {
  return * b ; 
}

inline  int A :: Pi  ( ) {
  return pi ;
}
# endif // CLASS_AI_HPP
```

Bi.hpp

```cpp
# ifndef  CLASS_BI_HPP
# define  CLASS_BI_HPP
# include "B.hpp"
# include "Ai.hpp"

inline  A & B :: theA ( ) {
  return * a ; 
}
      
inline  int B :: Pi  ( ) {
  return pi ;
}
# endif // CLASS_BI_HPP
```

A.cpp

```cpp
# include "Ai.hpp"
# include "Bi.hpp"

A :: A ( int const i ) : b { nullptr } , pi { i } {
}

void  A :: setB  ( B & l ) {
  b = & l ;
}
```

B.cpp

```cpp
# include "Bi.hpp"
# include "Ai.hpp"

B :: B ( int const i ) : a { nullptr } , pi { i } {
}

void  B :: setA  ( A & l ) {
  a = & l ;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
// g++ A.cpp B.cpp main.cpp -std=c++11 -o main
# include "Bi.hpp"
# include "Ai.hpp"

# include <iostream>

using std :: cout ;
using std :: endl ;

int main  ( ) {
  A a ( 1 ) ;
  B b ( 2 ) ;
  a . setB ( b ) ;
  b . setA ( a ) ;
  cout << "a.pi = " << a . Pi ( ) << endl ;
  cout << "b.pi = " << b . Pi ( ) << endl ;
  cout << "a.b.pi = " << a . theB ( ) . Pi ( ) << endl ;
  cout << "b.a.pi = " << b . theA ( ) . Pi ( ) << endl ;
}
```

Получается три уровня зависимости :

1. Предварительное объявление типа.
2. Определение класса с предварительно объявленными методами.
3. Инлайн методы в `.hpp`.
   Простые методы в `.cpp`.

Объявление класса может у себя включить предварительные объявления типов и классов, объекты которого которого включены в данный класс.
Определения методов могут у себя включать всё.