# Как использовать внутренние typedef обоих классов при взаимном включении заголовочных файлов?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header, препроцессор, typedef

**Введение:**

Допустим, есть два класса A и B, определённые каждый в своей паре файлов `.h` и `.cpp`. Код файлов представлен ниже:

Файл A.h

```cpp
#pragma once

class A
{
public:
    A(void);
    ~A(void);

    void f(B b);
};
```

Файл A.cpp:

```cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"


A::A(void)
{
}

A::~A(void)
{
}

void A::f(B b)
{

}
```

Файл B.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

class B
{
public:
    B(void);
    ~B(void);
    
    void f(A a);
};
```

Файл B.cpp

```cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

B::B(void)
{
}

B::~B(void)
{
}

void B::f(A a)
{

}
```

Если попытаться собрать такой проект, например, с таким файлом main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

получится ошибка, т.к. при компиляции файла B.cpp обнаружится, что в B.h тип A не определён, т.к. в файле B.cpp B.h был подключён раньше, чем A.h. Если поменять директивы включения местами, получим похожую ошибку, только уже при компиляции файла A.cpp.

Проблема давно известная и решается, насколько я знаю, следующим способом: порядок включения заголовочных файлов в каждом cpp-файле делается одинаковым (как уже сделано в коде выше), а в B.h добавляется строчка `class A;`, говорящая, что класс A есть, но про него компилятору расскажут попозже. Таким образом, описанная проблема решена. Но это только введение.

**Вопрос:**

Допустим теперь, что в каждом из классов есть внутренний `typedef`, более коротко и понятно определяющий умный указатель на данный класс. Более того, метод `f` в каждом из классов теперь принимает не объект другого класса, а тот самый умный указатель на него. Код классов видоизменяется следующим образом:

Файл A.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;

    A(void);
    ~A(void);

    void f(B::Ptr b);
};
```

Файл A.cpp:

```cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"


A::A(void)
{
}

A::~A(void)
{
}

void A::f(B::Ptr b)
{

}
```

Файл B.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class A;

class B
{
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<B> Ptr;

    B(void);
    ~B(void);
    
    void f(A::Ptr a);
};
```

Файл B.cpp

```cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"


B::B(void)
{
}

B::~B(void)
{
}

void B::f(A::Ptr a)
{

}
```

(использую Visual Studio 2008, поэтому такое пространство имён для `shared_ptr`).

И вот теперь начинаются действительно проблемы: при сборке, а именно при компиляции файла A.cpp, в файле B.h появляется ошибка

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'A'

что логично, поскольку я просто указал компилятору, что класс A существует, но не дал никаких гарантий, что внутри него есть соответствующий `typedef`.

Решение этой задачи костылём тоже известно: можно просто в файле B.h использовать не `typedef`, а полное определение типа, однако всё же хочется пользоваться удобствами укорочения имени типов, которые любезно предоставляет мне механизм `typedef`. Отсюда:

**Вопрос: как использовать `typedef` из обоих классов, если они объявлены во взаимно включённых заголовочных файлах?**

Comment: зачем в 2020 использовать Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: По мне этот вопрос не является дубликатом того вопроса

Comment: > "Проблема давно известная и решается, насколько я знаю, следующим способом: порядок включения заголовочных файлов в каждом cpp-файле делается одинаковым" - это очень плохое решение проблемы. Порядок включения хидеров не должен играть роли. Банальный форматтер может превратить ваш рабочий код в нерабочий просто отсортировав хидера по алфавиту. Чтобы такой проблемы избежать верным решением является `предекларация` (которую вы, кстати, упомянули, но только для `B.h`, хотя то же самое можно сделать и для `A.h`)

Comment: Что же касается проблемы описанной в вопросе: думаю сдесь проблема в архитектурной плоскости - лучше пересмотреть такую зависимость классов друг от друга. Что касается typedef для указателя на класс, то логичнее его было бы сделать снаружи класса, а не внутри него

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, удобно ведь, когда у каждого класса в его области видимости есть свой Ptr. Не нужно выдумывать название для typedef-ов на каждый класс наподобие `typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr`. Получается унифицированная запись – в каждом классе есть Ptr на него. А решать проблему только лишь предекларацией значит вообще отказаться от использования всего, что объявлено в пространстве имён каждого из классов. А это, опять же, удобно.

Comment: @user7860670, требование заказчика. Хотя к сути вопроса это вообще отношения не имеет.

Comment: Хмм, этот вопрос же вроде закрывался как дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013941/c-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8

Comment: @user7860670 не закрылся, как видите, потому что в "оригинале" речь вообще о другом.

Comment: Нет, в оригинале речь именно об этом - тут обычный случай циклической зависимости заголовочных файлов.

Comment: @user7860670 мой случай **не решается** способом, представленным в этом мнимом "оригнале". Я, кажется, упомянул это в вопросе. Дело не в циклической зависимости, а в `typedef` внутри классов.

Comment: Этот случай вполне решается аналогично тому. Вы хоть пробовали? typedef в этом случае и создает циклическую зависимость. И решением является разбиение циклической зависимости за счет вынесения зависимых сущностей наружу.

Comment: @V-Mor - похоже, что решением Вашей задачи будет "nested forward declaration" - то есть делать предварительное объявления для вложенных классов. Такое предложение в стандарт есть (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0289r0.pdf) но похоже к нему очень много вопросов.

Answer (score 3):

Предварительная декларации типов обычно заводят в отдельном хедере. А внутренние типы класса можно декларировать в личном пространстве имён класса. Отдельно от декларации самого класса. При компиляции сначала обрабатываются предварительно объявленные типы, а затем если надо то и сам класс.

Atype.h

```
class A ;
namespace nsA {
typedef std/*::tr1*/::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
}
```

Btype.h

```
class B ;
namespace nsB {
typedef std/*::tr1*/::shared_ptr<B> Ptr;
}
```

A.h

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

# include "Btype.h"

class A
{
public:

    A(void);
    ~A(void);

    void f(nsB::Ptr b);
};
```

B.h

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

# include "Atype.h"

class B
{
public:

    B(void);
    ~B(void);
    
    void f(nsA::Ptr a);
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"


A::A(void)
{
}

A::~A(void)
{
}

void A::f(nsB::Ptr b)
{

}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"


B::B(void)
{
}

B::~B(void)
{
}

void B::f(nsA::Ptr a)
{

}
```

Comment: Вы всё-таки вынесли определение `Ptr` из самого класса. Из-за этого тот факт, что данный `Ptr` относится именно к этому классу выражен менее явно. Возможно, Ваш вариант – единственное, что можно сделать в данной ситуации и, если так, я приму этот ответ как верный, но пока я всё-таки намерен подождать другие способы решения.

Answer (score 2):

Я сгласен с уже данным ответом, но как альтернативу могу предложить traits:

```
template<class>
struct traits;

template<>
struct traits<A>
{
   typedef ... Ptr;
};

template<>
struct traits<B>
{
   typedef ... Ptr;
};
```

Тоже таки вынести из класса, но ассоциация теснее.
И в классе можно подключить свои traits через наследование для того, чтобы иметь и вложенный синтаксис

```
struct A : public traits<A>
```

Comment: Шаблон можно было сделать один и по короче. Никак не могу привыкнуть чтобы класс мог быть родственным из-за типов другого класса. Может быть из-за его "изюминки"? ;)

Comment: Можно и без специализаций в данном случае, да. Я то срау предполагаю, что типы Ptr могут быть и несвязанными в общем случае, в частном можно упростить.