# Неверное определение типа принимаемого аргумента в классе

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt5, C++.
Проект средней величины. Существует несколько написанных классов, некоторые из которых принимают в параметрах указатели на экземпляры других классов для взаимодействия. Всё работает штатно и логично, например:

```
FirstClass::FirstClass(SecondClass * someObject) { someObject->BigRedButton->setDisabled(true); }
```

Всё реализуется, как завещали отцы: заголовные файлы с объявлением и `.cpp` файлы с реализацией. Однакое есть одно крайне не понятное мне поведение: некий класс (обыкновенный, с GUI-реализацией) не хочет выступать в качестве параметра. При указании ссылки на него в конструкторе любого другого класса и при попытке создать экземпляр этого класса, в сигнатуре вижу не `(StrangeClass *)`, а указатель на int *(!)* : `(int *)` .

Назовем загадочный класс `StrangeClass`. Он реализован канонично: заголовочный файл и файл реализации, ничего странного. Его header-файл:

```
class StrangeClass : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   QLabel * end_date;
   QLabel * label_logo;
   QPlainTextEdit * logWindow;
   QPushButton * bCalc;
   QPushButton * bExit;
   QPushButton * bTest;
   bool firstDisplay;

   public:
   std::vector<QPushButton*> buttons;
   QMainWindow * mainw;

   StrangeClass(FirstClass *); // в конструкторе используется ссылка на другой объект
   void start();

   ~StrangeClass();
   StrangeClass() = delete;
};
```

Я бы понял, если была бы какая-то логическая ошибка, дескать нельзя передать указатель на `StrangeClass` параметром в `SomeClass`, но дело и вопрос в том, почему QtCreator говорит мне, что я хочу передавать в конструктор указатель на `int`. Если в сигнатуру вписать любые другие ссылки и типы данных - всё воспринимается корректно, проблем с областью видимости нет, однако вместо `StrangeClass*` я вижу `int*`.

Надеюсь, смог понятно описать свою проблему. Были ли у Вас подобные грабли, как это решать, куда смотреть?

[image: Фрагменты скриншотов с кратким описанием]

Comment: а "как Вы это видите"? подсказки редактора, ошибки компилятора? и в целом, если не смотреть на это, оно компилируется и работает?

Comment: @KoVadim, забыл сделать важную пометку: с указанными, но не воспринимаемыми принимаемыми данными не компилируется, так же, как и в случае указания int*. В первую очередь вижу всплывающую подсказку при написании имени класса, где среда разработки подсказывает, что следует передать.

Comment: [C++ и циклические зависимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013941/c-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)

Comment: если есть ошибки компиляции/линковки, неплохо бы их показать

Comment: пока два варианта - либо Ваш класс пересекается с каким то системным классом, где есть такой конструктор, либо там где то затесался const у функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка крылась в рекурсивном включении хедер-файла: [image: наглядная иллюстрация]