# Ошибка при передаче объекта класса в конструктор другого по ссылке

Tags: c++

Я попытался указать в качестве аргумента для конструктора одного класса ссылку на другой класс, определенный в другом файле:

Camera.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cmath>
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#include "MoveMatrix.h"
#include "MainRender.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Camera
{
public:
    nc::NdArray <float> position_of_camera;
    nc::NdArray <float> forward_cam;
    nc::NdArray <float> up_cam;
    nc::NdArray <float> right_cam;

    float h_visibility;
    float v_visibility;

    float near_scene;
    float far_scene;

    float cZ;
    float cY;
    float cX;

    Camera(MainRender &render, float cx, float cy, float cz);

    nc::NdArray <float> translate_camera();
    nc::NdArray <float> rotate_camera();
    nc::NdArray <float> space_of_camera_matrix();
};
```

MainRender.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "3DObjectDescription.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "Projection.h"
#include "MoveMatrix.h"
#include <NumCpp.hpp>

class MainRender
{
public:
    sf::RenderWindow window;

    float RenderX;
    float RenderY;

    void create_objects_on_scene();
    void init();

    void draw();

    void main_loop();
};
```

На этапе компиляции ошибка:

**error: expected ')' before '&' token**

Я не знаю в чем причина ошибки, надеюсь, то Вы поможете разобраться!

Comment: Ошибка вообще на какую-то строку с конкретным номером в конкретном файле должна ссылаться.

Comment: 27 линия Camera.h

Comment: Может быть циклические инклуды у вас. Покажите их из `MoveMatrix.h`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, дык они и с показанными `Camera.h`/`MainRender.h` циклические... 2OP: добавь опережающее определение `class MainRender;` в начало `Camera.h` и/или убери `#include "Camera.h"` из `MainRender.h`.

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013941/c-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь определить класс `Camera` только после определения класса `MainRender`. И определить `MainRender` только после `Camera`. Происходит циклическая зависимость. С помощником `#pragma once` происходит такой порядок :

```
#include "MainRender.h"
  # include "Camera.h"
    #include "MainRender.h"
```

и стоп , `class MainRender` так и не будет определён для класса `Camera`.

Решается "предварительным" объявлением класса вместо полного.

Camera.h

```
// #include "MainRender.h"
class MainRender ;
```

MainRender.h

```
// #include "Camera.h"
// даже предварительного объявления пока не нужно
```

*спасибо быстрому совету **Fat-Zer***