# Error: expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c++

Мне кажется что я ошибся в архитектуре классов, тк ошибка весьма странно выглядит.
У меня несколько классов, тот с которым я работаю это DataTransmissionPC.

DataTransmissionPC.h

```
#include "ISerialPC.h"
#include "DataTransmissionBeb/src/DataTransmissionBeb.h"
class DataTransmissionPC : public DataTransmission {
public:
    DataTransmissionPC(ISerialPC* _iSerial);
}
```

DataTransmissionPC.cpp

```
#include "DataTransmissionPC.h"
DataTransmissionPC::DataTransmissionPC(ISerialPC* _iSerial) : DataTransmission(_iSerial) {}
```

ISerialPC.h

```
#include "DataTransmissionPC.h"
#include "DataTransmissionPC.h"
class ISerialPC : public ISerial {
    QSerialPort* initializationArduinoDevice();
public:
    ISerialPC();
QSerialPort* arduino;
void iWrite(const byte* val) override;
bool iWaitForReadyRead(int time) override;
```

ISerialPC.cpp

```
#include "ISerialPC.h"
ISerialPC::ISerialPC() {
    arduino = initializationArduinoDevice();
}
void ISerialPC::iWrite(const byte* val) {
    arduino->write();
}
bool ISerialPC::iWaitForReadyRead(int time = 30000) {
    return arduino->waitForReadyRead(time);
}
QSerialPort* ISerialPC::initializationArduinoDevice() {
//много кода....
}
```

DataTransmissionBeb.h

```
class ISerial { 
public:
    virtual void iWrite(const byte* val) = 0;
    virtual bool iWaitForReadyRead(int time) = 0;
};

class DataTransmission {
protected:
    const size_t sizeSendBuf = 256;
    const size_t sizeReceivedBuf = 512;

    byte* sendMes = new byte[sizeSendBuf];
    byte* receivedMes = new byte[sizeReceivedBuf];
public:
    ISerial* iSerial;
    void clearBufMes(byte* mes, size_t& sizeMes);
    DataTransmission(ISerial* _iSerial);
    ~DataTransmission();
};
```

DataTransmissionBeb.cpp

```
#include <DataTransmissionBeb/src/DataTransmissionBeb.h>
DataTransmission::DataTransmission(ISerial* _iSerial) {
    iSerial = _iSerial;
    clearBufMes(sendMes, sizeSendMes);
    clearBufMes(receivedMes, sizeReceivedMes);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ISerialPC.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ISerialPC *iArduino = new ISerialPC;
    DataTransmissionPC* dateTrans = new DataTransmissionPC(iArduino);

    delete dateTrans;
    delete iArduino;
}
```

Ошибки:
1)

```
...\DataTransmissionPC.h:14: ошибка: expected ')' before '*' token
In file included from ISerialPC.h:3:0,
                 from main.cpp:9:
DataTransmissionPC.h:14:33: error: expected ')' before '*' token
     DataTransmissionPC(ISerialPC* _iSerial);
```

2. ...\main.cpp:20: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'DataTransmissionPC::DataTransmissionPC(ISerialPC*&)'
   main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
   main.cpp:20:68: error: no matching function for call to 'DataTransmissionPC::DataTransmissionPC(ISerialPC*&)'
   DataTransmissionPC* dateTrans = new DataTransmissionPC(iArduino);
3. ...\ISerialPC.h:3: In file included from ISerialPC.h:3:0,
   In file included from ISerialPC.h:3:0,
   from main.cpp:9:
   DataTransmissionPC.h:8:7: note: candidate: constexpr DataTransmissionPC::DataTransmissionPC(const DataTransmissionPC&)
   class DataTransmissionPC : public DataTransmission {
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   DataTransmissionPC.h:8:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ISerialPC*' to 'const DataTransmissionPC&'
4. ...\DataTransmissionPC.h:14: ошибка: expected ')' before '*' token
   In file included from ISerialPC.h:3:0,
   from ISerialPC.cpp:1:
   DataTransmissionPC.h:14:33: error: expected ')' before '*' token
   DataTransmissionPC(ISerialPC* _iSerial);
5. :-1: ошибка: [Makefile.Debug:438: debug/main.o] Error 1

Что я сделал тут не так, и как надо подобное делать?

Comment: Как минимум у вас в первом же файле отсутствует точка с запятой после объявления класса `DataTransmissionPC`...

Comment: Циклические зависимости следует устранить и вообще привести инклюды в надлежащий вид и подправить ошибки синтаксиса.

Comment: Плюс ко всему.... хотя многим не нравится(не будем говорить по именам), когда  говоришь не только об ответе на вопрос, но я  все же спрошу.  Вы знаете для чего заголовочные файлы вообще? Если знаете, то для вопроса достаточно было представить их. Для чего кому то ваша реализация, тем более, что  она далеко не образцовая?

Comment: По поводу архитектуры: конкретно заданные константные  размеры в DataTransmission явно указывают, что они должны быть статическими, а  указателям на массивы лучше быть именами статических массивов, а не указателями на динамический массив, так как ни один из функций членов не освобождает память под массив и не изменяет значения указателя, кроме деструктора. Ну и далее... В целом хорошо писать класс, если вы собираетесь придать смысл этому типу .   Тут нет такого впечатления...

Comment: циклические инклуды `DataTransmissionPC.h` <-> `ISerialPC.h` кажется это дубль ошибки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C++ и циклические зависимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013941/c-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)